# How can a user filter video results by language on YouTube?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-dl, android-youtube-api

If i searched for ( how to install "thing goes here") but it shows videos from channels that are from united states , would that be possible?

Tried changing my location in YouTube , didn't work.
Dont know if there is any third party sites that could help.